# How to load XML file from internet into a string

Tags: java, xml, string, sax, gnu-fileutils

Currently I have a java application that loads XML from a local file into a string.  My code looks like this

```
     private String xmlFile = "D:\\mylocalcomputer\\extract-2339393.xml";
     String fileStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(xmlFile));
```

How can I get the contents of the XML file if it was located on the internet, at a URL like http://mydomain.com/xml/extract-2000.xml  ?

Answer (score 2):

try the sax interface

```
private String xmlURL = "http://mydomain.com/xml/extract-2000.xml";

XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(handler);
reader.parse(new InputSource(new URL(xmlURL).openStream()));
```

For more information regarding SAX check [this link](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html)

Comment: Hi, I am using SAX, but unfortunately, I need to load the XML into a string and manipulate it first.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("http://mydomain.com/xml/extract-2000.xml"));
  org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
  StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
  Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
  serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stw));
  stw.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for Transformer.  I would recommend using a StreamSource rather than a DOMSource to improve performance.